# math module not available by default in python3

Tags: python, math, module

I am using following python version in Debian Stable Linux:

```
Python 3.5.3 (default, Jan 19 2017, 14:11:04) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170118] on linux
```

I find following code does not work:

```
print(math.sqrt(10))
```

The error is:

```
    print(math.sqrt(10))
NameError: name 'math' is not defined
```

This error disappears and code works fine if following is added:

```
import math
```

This seems inconsistent with documentation on https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/math.html where it says `This module is always available`. Where is the problem? Is there some problem in my python setup?

Comment: Human language is ambiguous, that's it. `always available` means you are always available to import it.

Comment: I think it should be clarified in documentation (preferably at beginning of page) that `import math` is needed.

Comment: In python, everything named module need to be imported before using. This is a very basic principle, so if you see `This module`, OK, you know it should be imported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong with the setup. The phrase

> This module is always available

simply means that in every environment you should be able to import the standard `math` module.

Since that phrase states that what you are seeing is a module and it also stated in Python's documentation that modules need to be imported I wouldn't call it inconsistent.

Comment: You are correct, but I read the statement and concluded the same as the OP.

Comment: @copper.hat I too believe that the phrasing could be better to facilitate beginners, but in my view, this is not enough to be characterized as inconsistent. I think it is exactly the same when saying *printf() is always available in C*. You still need to *#include<stdio.h>* to use it, but it is available nonetheless and every programmer knows that it needs to be included.